# Alternative to QLineEdit to get a double

Tags: qt, qlineedit

I have a QLineEdit which I use to get a double. But is there a more suitable way to get it? Here it is my code.

```
ui->lineEdit->setValidator(new QIntValidator(this));

QString XMAX=ui->lineEdit->text();
double xmax=XMAX.toDouble();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The canonical way to input a double is of course to use a [QDoubleSpinBox](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qdoublespinbox.html).

If you insist on using a `QLineEdit`, you should use it together with a `QDoubleValidator` instead of your `QIntValidator`. I would just add a sanity check that something has been entered into the edit field:

```
double xmax;
if (ui->lineEdit->text()->isEmpty())
    xmax = numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
else
    xmax = ui->lineEdit->text().toDouble();
```

Comment: Using QDoubleSpinBox I have to have the up and down arrow, which i don't want to.

Comment: @SamuelNLP: Ok, then stick with a line edit. Just use the correct validator and check that the line edit is not empty.

Comment: @SamuelNLP to get rid of the arrows you can simply use the method `setButtonSymbols(QAbstractSpinBox::NoButtons)` of the `QDoubleSpinBox`